# webpack is not recognized as a internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: npm, webpack

I am Learning React.js and i am using windows 8 OS.i have navigate to my root folder

```
1.Created the package.json file by npm init
2. install webpack by npm install -S webpack.now webpack has been downloaded to my modules folder
3. install webpack globally by typing npm install webpack -g
4. i am also having a webpack.config.js in my root folder which contains the source and ouput directory
5. when i type the webpack command i am getting the below error.
```

**webpack is not recognized as a internal or external command,operable program or batch file**

Comment: I had this problem, but after  restarting IDE (PHPStorm in my case) problem was solved

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I had this issue for a long time too. (webpack installed globally etc. but still not recognized)
It turned out that I haven't specified enviroment variable for npm (where is file webpack.cmd sitting)
So I add to my Path variable

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

If you are using Powershell, you can type the following command to effectively add to your path :

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\", "User")
```

**IMPORTANT :** Don't forget to close and re-open your powershell window in order to apply this.

Comment: well Iam stuck at the same place...Can u please elaborate ur answer

Comment: I was following all the steps but it did not work then finally I realized, I did not open CMD as administrator.

Comment: Better set to %APPDATA%\npm

Answer (score 231):

Better solution to this problem is to install `Webpack` globally.

This always works and it worked for me. Try below command.

```
npm install -g webpack
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that using the -g installs webpack globally, which you may not want if you have multiple projects that may require different versions of webpack.

Comment: I also ran `npm install -g webpack-cli`. Now it works.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server/v/4.9.3) recommend local installation over global. "`webpack-dev-server` will always use a local installation over a global one."

Answer (score 104):

As an alternative, if you have Webpack installed locally, you can explicitly specify where Command Prompt should look to find it, like so:

```
node_modules\.bin\webpack
```

(This does assume that you're inside the directory with your `package.json` and that you've already run `npm install webpack`.)

Comment: Agree with Max, the reason being that it is recommended to have webpack installed locally (in devDependencies) - My problem was a little different though, when adding webpack as a pre build step in VS 2017, I thought VS was smart enough to find the webpack cmd locally without the full path

Comment: @JimiSweden did you try adding `node_modules\.bin` to _tools->configure external tools_

Comment: You could try using `npx webpack` which also checks `./node_modules/.bin` instead of fiddling with paths.

Comment: This is the only answer that has worked for me as of yet.

Answer (score 58):

`npm install -g webpack-dev-server` will solve your issue

Comment: It may solve the error message OP posted, but this is not a good solution to the problem as it adds more dependencies than _just_ solving the missing webpack. See any of the other high-voted answers for better alternatives.

Comment: As pointed out by different contributors already (see other answers/comments), installing globally is considered bad practice as it locks you down to one version. See also https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/

Comment: I faced this problem and your solution work very nicely to solve my problem `'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`

Answer (score 34):

Try deleting *node_modules* in local directory and re-run *npm install*.

Comment: This worked for me because I previously deleted `.bin` folder to fix an issue with `npm install` which introduced this issue instead.

Answer (score 26):

Maybe a clean install will fix the problem. This "command" removes all previous modules and re-installs them, perhaps while the webpack module is incompletely downloaded and installed.

```
npm clean-install
```

Comment: This is most likely the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 16):

Add webpack command as an npm script in your package.json.

```
{
    "name": "react-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "compile": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
    }
}
```

Then run

> npm run compile

When the webpack is installed it creates a binary in ./node_modules/.bin folder. npm scripts also looks for executable created in this folder

Comment: does not work - npm install -g webpack-dev-server is correct command

Answer (score 13):

Webpack CLI is now in a separate package and must be installed globally in order to use the 'webpack' command:

```
npm install -g webpack-cli
```

**EDIT:** Much has changed. Webpack folks do not recommend installing the CLI globally (or separately for that matter). This issue should be fixed now but the proper install command is:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

This answer was originally intended as a "work-around" for the OPs problem.

Comment: "must be installed globally" is not correct as I understand it. Even the webpack folks advise against it. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/

Answer (score 7):

```
npx webpack
```

It is worked for me. I'm using Windows 10 and I installed webpack locally.

Answer (score 6):

We also experienced this problem and I like all the answers that suggest using a script defined in `package.json`.

For our solutions we often use the following sequence:

1. `npm install --save-dev webpack-cli` (if you're using webpack v4 or later, otherwise use `npm install --save-dev webpack`, see [webpack installation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/), retrieved 19 Jan 2019)
2. `npx webpack`

Step 1 is a one-off. Step 2 also checks `./node_modules/.bin`. You can add the second step as a npm script to `package.json` as well, for example:

```
{
   ...
   "scripts": {
      ...
      "build": "npx webpack --mode development",
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

and then use `npm run build` to execute this script.

Tested this solution with npm version 6.5.0, webpack version 4.28.4 and webpack-cli version 3.2.1 on Windows 10, executing all commands inside of a PowerShell window. My nodejs version is/was 10.14.2. I also tested this on Ubuntu Linux version 18.04.

I'd advise against installing webpack globally, in particular if you are working with a lot of different projects each of which may require a different version of webpack. Installing webpack globally locks you down to a particular version across all projects on the same machine.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked to install webpack separately. So simply:

```
$npm install
$npm install webpack
```

I'm not sure why this should be necessary, but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

This below-given commands worked for me.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g webpack
```

**Note** - Run these commands as administrator. Once installed then close your command prompt and restart it to see the applied changes.

Answer (score 3):

Just run your command line (cmd) as an administrator.

Answer (score 3):

I've had same issue and just added the code block into my package.json file;

```
 "scripts": {
   "build": "webpack -d --progress --colors"
 }
```

and then run command on terminal;

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to install webpack and webpack-cli in the same scope.

```
npm i -g webpack webpack-cli
```

or,

```
npm i webpack webpack-cli
```

if you install it locally you need to call it specifially

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack -v
```

Comment: Or, if installed locally, you could use `npx webpack` (tested with npm version 6.5.0, webpack 4.28.4 and webpack-cli 3.2.1)

Comment: that's the ticket

Comment: npm i -g webpack webpack-cli

Answer (score 3):

Install WebPack globally

```
npm install --global webpack
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when upgrading to **React 16.12.0**.

I had two errors one regarding **webpack** and the other regarding the **store** when rendering the DOM.

**Webpack Error:**

> webpack is not recognized as a internal or external command,operable program or batch file

**Webpack Solution:**

1. Close related VS Solution
2. Delete `node_modules` folder
3. Deleted `package-lock.json`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm rebuild`
6. Repeated this 2-3 times

**Store Error:**

> Type Store<()> is not assignable to type Store<any, AnyAction>

**Store Solution:**

Suggestions to update my React version didn't fix this error for me, but irrespective I would recommend doing it.

My code ended up looking like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store as any}>
            <ConnectedApp />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

As per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961024/property-symbol-observable-is-missing-in-type-storeapplicationstate-but/56973395)

Answer (score 3):

If you create a boilerplate folder for your JS projects so that you can use JS Modules, `webpack` and `Babel` are great tools.

Don't install `webpack` globally and after installing the most recent versions of both, your `package.json` file will be loaded up and ready to copy for future projects.

Make sure to delete the `node_modules` folder to decrease file size in your boilerplate folder and then to reinstall node_modules use `npm install`.

I forgot to run npm install and kept getting this error when trying to run my webpack dev-server until I realized I needed to run `npm install` to install `node_modules` and then it worked.

Comment: Delete node_modules + npm install got me going again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have just cloned a repo, you first need to run

```
npm install
```

The error your getting will be generated if you are missing project dependencies. The above command will download and install them.

Answer (score 2):

I also Face the same issue this command works for me

**`npm install --save-dev webpack`**

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, none of the solutions worked for me, I reinstalled node and that repaired my environment, everything works again.

Comment: This is what I had to do as well. I tried at least three other "solutions" provided on here and none worked except for uninstalling and reinstalling Node again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this folks, the cli needs to be updated to the latest version

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

credit goes go to R.Richards
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526528/1908827

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was locally installing webpack as devDependency. Although I have it as `devDependencies` it was not installed in node_modules folder. So I ran
`npm install --only=dev`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solve it like this `npm i`

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes **npm install -g webpack** does not save properly. Better to use **npm install webpack --save** . It worked for me.

Comment: -g installs globally (not your local project node_modules + package.json) while --save installs locally (in your local node_modules + package.json) so this answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem and I couldn't figure it out. I went through every line of code and couldn't find my error. Then I realized that I installed webpack in the wrong folder. My error was not paying attention to the folder I was installing webpack to.