# Global Angular CLI version greater than local version

Tags: angular-cli

When running `ng serve` I get this warning about my global CLI version being greater than my local version. I don't notice any issues from this warning, but I was wondering if the two versions should be in sync? Also, Is it necessary to have a local version if you have a global version?

The warning:

> Your global Angular CLI version (1.1.1) is greater than your local version (1.0.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Comment: Can anyone answer *why* we need both local and global?

Answer (score 648, accepted):

To answer one of the questions, it is necessary to have both a global and local install for the tools to work.

If you try to run `ng serve` on an application without the local install of the CLI (global install only), you will get the following error.

> You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the serve command.

It will also print this message:

```
Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"
```

Run that `npm` command to update the CLI locally, and avoid the warning that you are getting.

Other question: It looks like they do not *have* to be in sync, but it's probably best that they are in order to avoid any unusual behavior with the tool, or any inconsistencies with the code the tool generates.

*Why do we need both the global install, and a local install?*

The global install is needed to start a new application. The `ng new <app-name>` command is run using the global installation of the CLI. In fact, if you try to run `ng new` while inside the folder structure of an existing CLI application, you get this lovely error:

> You cannot use the `new` command inside an Angular CLI project.

Other commands that can be run from the global install are `ng help`, `ng get/set` with the `--global` option, `ng version`, `ng doc`, and [`ng completion`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-autocompletion).

The local install of the CLI is used after an application has been built. This way, when new versions of the CLI are available, you can update your global install, and not affect the local install. This is good for the stability of a project. Most `ng` commands only make sense with the local version, like `lint`, `build` and `serve`, etc.

According to the CLI GitHub [readme](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli), to update the CLI you must update the global and local package. However, I have used the CLI where the global and local version vary without any trouble so far. If I ever run across an error related to having the global and local CLI versions out of sync, I will post that here.

Comment: there is no way instead of updating the cli , for example i want to run installing modules with t my existing cli version  . or there is no way to force when executing command to use the local cli not the global one  ??

Comment: The local version of the CLI is used by default when running commands in a CLI project directory. It says as much in the warning.

Comment: but i don't know why this solution is not working for me . what if i mention in my package.json as value of my angular-cli ="^1.0.6" . that work but still not understading  what happen ?

Comment: npm uninstall -g @angular/cli, npm cache clear --force, npm install @angular/cli

Comment: It is okay to have different versions of dependencies on the local project and globally (angular-cli is one dependency). And you should take care to plan the upgrade to the latest version of a dependency for your local project. Read the instructions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli.

Comment: good read, I tried using different cli version v6 and ang v1.7.3 and looks like they're not in a conflict. Does the `ng -g component-name`  use the local cli?

Comment: I have a number of Angular4 projects that I can't currently upgrade, but want to create new projects in Angular6 going forward.  So am I correct in understanding from what you're saying here that I can upgrade my global Angular CLI to Angular6 and if I `ng serve` or `ng build` the Angular4 projects they would use their local Angular4 CLI and therefore not be affected by the installation of the global Angular6 CLI?

Comment: @Doug That is correct. You will get a warning when running those commands for a project with a lower version of the CLI, but you can ignore it. All the warning says is versions are different, and the local CLI will be used.

Comment: Is there some way to actually manage angular and its packages on a project?  I feel like I do this infrequently enough that each time I have to re-learn what not to do.

Comment: @Mark [ng update](https://angular.io/cli/update) is probably the closest thing out there for that.

Comment: Its odd, ng update didn't do anything, claims there are things to update.  I run 'npm update' then the packages update.

Answer (score 207):

This is how I solved the issue.

[image: Install latest Angular CLI package locally]

Copy and run these commands

```
ng --version
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
ng --version
```

Comment: I would add that step 1.5 (if you will) is: `rm node_modules/.bin/ng`. Worked perfectly.

Comment: How can we install it to specific version? My global version is 6.2.9 where as my local version is 1.7.5. I  tried  npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6 command but no luck

Comment: after doing this my ng serve dont work, the command dont excute and dont even give me an exception

Answer (score 66):

This works for me:
it will update local version to latest

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

to verify version

```
  ng --version
```

Comment: I converted that into an old-skool Windoze batch command:
    CALL npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli
    CALL npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
    CALL npm install
    CALL ng --version

Comment: Did your steps.  Tried `ng serve --open` and got   "This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ "

Comment: This one worked for me, from Angular 13 to 14.

Answer (score 36):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then in your Local project package:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm i 
ng update @angular/cli 
ng update @angular/core
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Was getting below error 
Error: Unexpected end of JSON input
Unexpected end of JSON input
Above steps helped from this post [Can't update angular to version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543318/cant-update-angular-to-version-6/50543790)

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular - did helped ng update @angular/cli   -> did create angular.json and other updates.

Answer (score 19):

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Your existing configuration can be updated automatically by running the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

or:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I just used this command into project:

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 9):

**Update Angular CLI for workspace (Local)**

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

**Note: Make sure to install the global version using the command with ‘-g’ is if it installed properly**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**Run Update command to get a list of all dependencies required to be upgraded**

```
ng update
```

**Next Run update command as below for each individual Angular core package**

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

**However, I had to add ‘–force’ and ‘–allow-dirty’ flags additionally to fix all other pending issues**

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

Answer (score 8):

Run the following Command: `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

After running the above command the console might popup the below message

> The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your
>   existing configuration can be updated automatically by running the
>   following command:   ng update @angular/cli

Answer (score 8):

Two ways to solve this global and local angular CLI version issue.
1. Keep a specific angular-cli version for both environments.
2. Goto latest angular-cli version for both environments.

**1. Specific angular-cli version**

First, find out which angular version you want to keep on the global and local environment.

```
ng --version
```

**for example:** here we keeping local angular CLI version 8.3.27

So, we have to change the global version also on 8.3.27.
use cmd>

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@8.3.27 -g
```

here, '-g' flag for a set global angular-cli version.

**2. Goto latest angular version for both CLI environment.**

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest -g  
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not fluent in English

but if I understand the problem, is it that locally in the project you have an older version of CLI than globally?

And would you like to use this global newer instead of the local older one?

If so, a very simple method is enough to run  in the project directory `npm link @angular/cli`

more in the subject on the page: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 6):

You just need to update the AngularCli

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 5):

First find out the global angular-cli version by running

```
ng --version
```

The above code will show what version is the global and local angular-cli versions.

If you want the global and local angular cli to be same you can just do

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.7.4
```

where 1.7.4 is your global angular-cli version

Then if you run `ng serve --open` your code should run.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I fixed it. in `Visual Studio Code`'s terminal, First cache clean

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then updated `cli`

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

If any module missing after this, use below command

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use the Angular framework in your projects, it has two different versions: a global Angular version and a local Angular version, installed directly in your project. It is the difference between its two versions that explains the display of the error message "Global Angular CLI version greater than local version". You have to understand the difference between the two versions to then be able to solve this problem.
to solve that, run this command:

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

```html
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to avoid the global installation to **create a new application**.
In my case I'm using Angular 9 but the customer requires Angular 8.

```sh
# create an empty directories
mkdir angular-8-cli
mkdir my-angular-8-project

# init empty npm project
cd angular-8-cli
npm init -y

# install local angular 8 cli
npm i @angular/cli@8

# go to your angular 8 project
cd ../my-angular-8-project

# use previously installed angular 8 cli to create a new angular 8 project
../angular-8-cli/node_modules/.bin/ng new my-angular-8-project --directory=.
```

Answer (score 2):

if you upgraded your Angular Version, you need to change the version of

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular
```

inside your

```
package.json
```

from your old version to the new angular build version upgraded.

I had upgraded to Angular 10, so i needed to go to
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular
and check which is my version according to Angular 10.

In my case, i founded that the version needs to be `0.1001.7`, so i changed my old version to this version in my package.json and run

```
npm --save install
```

That was enough.

Answer (score 2):

- ng version

**npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest**

- **Close** the **command prompt** and open again
- ng version
- if your **PowerShell** not recognize the ng command run this command in your powershell :

Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope currentuser -executionpolicy remotesigned

Answer (score 1):

If you just wish to turn off this warning, run the command

```
ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false
```

This is useful because some times you want to have different local & global versions. For example, you might have the latest Angular for your global version as you'll use it on new projects, but will have to run an old project in older Angular version.

Answer (score 1):

// install npm check updates

```
npm i -g npm -check-updates
```

// Run npm-check-updates

```
npm -u
```

// you should then get a list of all your packages to be updated to the newest version

// Install the updated packages as prompted

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error, update your global or local version so that the versions of the Angular CLI match.

SOLUTION 1)
npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev
[OR]
SOLUTION 2)
To install a specific version of the Angular CLI locally
npm install @angular/cli@X.y.z --save-dev

To install a specific version of the Angular CLI globally
npm install -g @angular/cli@X.y.z

If you get an error with commands, add ( --legacy-peer-deps) property.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused because global and local angular versions are different. To update global angular version, first you need to run the following command in command prompt or vs code terminal

```sh
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

After that if there are any vulnerability found then run the following command to fix them

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

npm ng install /config --save-dev -dev @angular/cli@latest @angular-devkit/build-angular -global -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this warning even if I am not in any angular project,

later I realized that I have mistakenly created the angular project in the root folder directly and forgot to delete the `node_modules`, `package.json`, and `package-lock.json`

So no matter which directory I move into I was getting this warning.

If you want to find where your local version is coming from then run the below command

```
npm ls @angular/cli --depth=0
```

The above command will print the directory from where the current angular version is being used, and once you delete the `node_modules` the warning also disappeared

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run angular using local version i.e the version that the project is using use the below syntax to run:

`npx ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@15.0.2

use this to update to specific global version installed

Answer (score -1):

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular - did helped ng update @angular/cli   -> did create angular.json and other updates.

Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 58 dependencies.

```
 ** Executing migrations for package '@angular/cli' **
            Updating karma configuration
            Updating configuration
            Removing old config file (.angular-cli.json)
            Writing config file (angular.json)
            Some configuration options have been changed, please make sure to update any  npm scripts which you may have modified. DELETE .angular-cli.json CREATE angular.json (4394 bytes) CREATE browserslist (429 bytes) UPDATE karma.conf.js (993 bytes) UPDATE public/tsconfig.spec.json (295 bytes) UPDATE package.json (2618 bytes) UPDATE tsconfig.json (437 bytes) UPDATE tslint.json (3135 bytes) UPDATE public/polyfills.ts (587 bytes) UPDATE public/tsconfig.app.json (199 bytes) npm WARN @angular/core@5.2.9 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do these things

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm audit fix
npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: As this question is nearly 3 years old and has 14 existing answers, your answer would be much more valuable if you explained why your answer is of value that wasn't covered by all of the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

Specify the module using the --module parameter. For example, if the main module is app.module.ts, run this:

```
ng g c new-component --module app
```

Or if you are in an other directory then

```
ng g c component-name --module ../
```

Answer (score -2):

this should solve the issue:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```