# Your global Angular CLI version is greater than your local

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i've installed the latest angular-cli on a fresh machine and i'm trying to serve a project generated with a previous cli version

i got this warning

```
Your global Angular CLI version (1.6.4) is greater than your local
version (1.6.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
```

Although the project works correctly what have i do in order to update my project with latest dependecies and avoid this message (avoid not suppress!)

this is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "AngularTest",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "angular-cli": {},
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
        "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 4201 --hmr -e=hmr",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
        "e2e": "protractor"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
        "@aspnet/signalr-client": "1.0.0-preview1-27891",
        "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
        "@types/jquery.blockui": "0.0.28",
        "@types/jquery.validation": "^1.16.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
        "@types/signalr": "^2.2.33",
        "@types/toastr": "^2.1.33",
        "abp-ng2-module": "^1.3.0",
        "abp-web-resources": "^3.3.0",
        "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
        "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
        "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "jquery-countto": "^1.2.0",
        "jquery-migrate": "^3.0.0",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
        "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
        "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
        "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.0",
        "node-waves": "^0.7.5",
        "push.js": "1.0.4",
        "raphael": "^2.2.7",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "signalr": "^2.2.1",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
        "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
        "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
        "toastr": "^2.1.2",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.27",
        "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "nswag": "^11.12.7",
        "protractor": "^5.1.1",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.7.0",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)

Comment: Instead of upgrading all of my packages, I would rather downgrade my CLI version.

Comment: use this solution for upgrade and update your `Angular-cli`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version/48294993#48294993

Answer (score 4):

The warning shows that your local app cli version is lower than your global cli version. So if you want to stop that warning you need to locally install specific angular cli version.

Use this command

`npm install --save @angular/cli@wished.version.here`

In your case

`npm install --save @angular/cli@1.6.4`

Answer (score 3):

[Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.0) is greater than your local
version (1.6.1). The local Angular CLI version is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npvUN.png)

You can update local version to latest by using:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular/cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

to verify version

```
  ng --version
```

Answer (score 2):

You Need to upgrade your project user CLI version.
I recommend to take backup, then:
1- Make sure you are in your project folder.
2- Run

```
ng update --all
```

to update all packages, or you can run

```
ng update @angular/core
```

for Upgrading Core Packages only, but I recommend upgrading all packages.

After this you can run your application as normal.

Comment: Quote: '--all' functionality has been removed as updating multiple packages at once is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I manually updated the package.json to "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0" and also deleted the node_modules/@angular/cli module, before issuing npm install @angular/cli.

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your getting this message

"Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.0) is greater than your local version (1.6.1). The local Angular CLI version is used".

You just need to update your local version to the global version.

First type the command
**npm uninstall --save-dev angular/cli**

Let it uninstall the current version

Then
**npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest**

Now it has been updated to the latest version.
To check that simply run the command
**ng --version**

Now all set...
Go to the terminal and type **ng serve**

Thanks,
Gani

Answer (score 1):

The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installed a temporary version to perform the update.

**solution**

`npm install --save @angular/cli@(latest version) -g`

If we suppose we want the Angular version `10.2.0`
We will write the command:

```
npm install --save @angular/cli@10.2.0 -g
```

Answer (score 0):

️ install the latest version of the Angular CLI locally

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev
```

️ install the latest version of the Angular CLI globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

if errors persists

️ delete node_modules and package-lock.json (Windows)

```
rd /s /q "node_modules"
del package-lock.json
del -f yarn.lock
```

️ delete node_modules and package-lock.json (macOS/Linux)

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
rm -f yarn.lock
```

️ clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install
```