# Why do we need local and global angular-cli version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have noticed that I have a local and global angular/cli package installed.

When angular/cli local package is used compared to global one ?

Comment: you cannot use angular-cli commands such as `ng generate` without the global version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version/44526528?s=1|36.0676#44526528

Comment: yeah exactly. You can't generate a project without the global version.

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta what about local one, when is it used ?

Comment: WHy the thumbs down.. this is a valid question

Answer (score 1):

local package will used from angular cli self. If you using ng on a terminal the global installation is used. 
To building by typescript files, i using the local cli installation.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use **ng** cmd in terminal, it will look into global packages instead of node_modules folder

( local installation ) e.g.

```
wayne@bruce...PC:~/Desktop/myFirstApp$ ng serve -o
```

2. If you execute it through npm cmd like

   wayne@bruce...PC:~/Desktop/myFirstApp$ npm start

and in **package.json** something like this

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve -o",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "deploy": "ng deploy",
  "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json",
  "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/app/stats-es2015.json"}
```

Then it will look into **node_modules** folder i.e. **local installation**

In both cases same cmd will be executed.