# When and Where Angular CLI Has Been Installed Locally?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After installing `Node.js`, I imported an Angular project from GitHub on VSCode, then I run the following usual commands successively:

```
npm install                      //This one created node_modules folder, but I don't have angular cli yet, because ng is still not recognized!
npm install -g @angular/cli      //Then after the installation of the global CLI finished..
ng --version
```

Now I get the following warning:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.5) is greater than your local version (7.3.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version) is trying to explain that `warning`, but they are not explaining where and when the local CLI is installed, at least in my case here.

Please give some clarification, thanks.

**Edit**

Here are the dependencies in `pakage.json`, according to your comments, they are related, but what is the usual scenarios if there is no explicit CLI version definition?.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular-formio": "^3.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootswatch": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
```

Comment: Doing npm install probably installs ng cli locally if specified in package.json file, it does not get automatically into PATH environment variable. To execute it you will need npx command i.e.: npx ng ..... Please post your devDependencies so we will be able to investigate.

Comment: @DariuszOstolski Thank you for note, I updated.

Comment: Try entering `@angular/cli` and version `~7.3.1` in the [npm semantic version calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/). You'll see that version `7.3.2` could be installed based on that pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The global version** is installed with `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.

**The local version** is inside of your project in `node_modules` under `node_modules/@angular/cli`. You have to update your `package.json` to the same version as your global version.

The `@angular/cli` is installed locally when you run `ng new appName`.

And it is installed with every run of `npm install` in your project root.

**To update it** you need to change this line in `package.json`

```
...
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.2",
...
```

To this

```
...
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.5",
...
```

And then run `npm install`

Comment: Thank you, That is the answer to `Where`, what about `When`?

Comment: @SourceCode It installed "locally" when you executed command `npm install` based on the version specified in `package.json`. What is the version number listed in `package.json` for `@angular/cli`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thank you, I updated, it does not seems to be the one in the message! No 3.2.

Answer (score 4):

You have cloned an angular project from github, it has a file named `package.json`, which tells `npm` which packages to install when you do `npm install`.

So, in your `package.json`, please lookup for `"@angular/cli"` in `devDependencies`,  you will find the version written something like this

```
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.2"
```

This is the local version of `@angular/cli`.

when you ran `npm install`, it installed that version`(7.3.2)` of Angular CLI, AKA local version.

but when you ran `npm install -g @angular/cli`, it automatically installed the latest version globally (the `-g` flag in the install command). And, the latest version was `7.3.5`. Hence, it is giving the warning that the local version is not same and it is using the local version of Angular CLI