# Getting Error while upgrading from Angular 6 to Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to upgrade my Angular 6.2.4 application to Angular 8.0.2
I followed the steps given on angular.io for up gradation. But keep getting this error when I enter the "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core" command

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.2) is greater than your local
version (6.2.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.0.0").
                  Package "@angular/material-moment-adapter" has a missing peer dependency of "moment" @ "^2.18.1".
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "6.1.9" (extended), would install "8.0.0").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^6.1.0" (extended), would install "8.0.0").
                  Package "ngx-loading" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.0.0").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.0.0").
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

Please help me to upgrade my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your local Angular version.
Open a command prompt, go to the folder where is located your packages.json and type :
`ng update @angular/cli`