# Angular npm install not working after git pull

Tags: angular, npm, installation, npm-install

My issue is, when I take pull from the git there is a angular project which have `angular ^7.1.0`, but my local global version is `angular 8`.

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.5) is greater than your local
version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

What can be the solution for this?

Below is error screen-shot for the error when i run `ng serve`:

> This usually happens because your environment has changed since
>   running `npm install`. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the
>   binding for your current environment.

[image: Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)

Comment: @Ismail i have seen that, not working

Comment: Is Node.js 10.x installed on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run npm rebuild node-sass

and re-run npm install again

Comment: Did you run 'npm rebuild node-sass' in your project folder or globally ? If you did it globally, try to run it inside of your project folder

Answer (score 0):

Both your global and project's angular-cli version should be in sync. Try downgrading your global version or update the project's angular-cli version to avoid this error.

in your case can update the angular cli of your project to this latest using the command,

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

or uninstall the global angular cli and install specific version as per your need,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@{version}
```

If you are not keen on updating, you could try using the global cli version in your local project using npm link by running the following command in your project,

```
npm link @angular/cli
```