# What is global anguar CLI and local angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I do ng build --prod --aot, I get something like:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.19) is greater than your local version (8.3.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

I resolved the above warning. But, I want to know what is global angular CLI actually is and what is local angular CLI? I've searched it. But, couldn't make myself clear.

Comment: No, I resolved my issue. But, my question is what actually is global and local cli? Is it my projects cli version and my systems cli version?

Comment: It is explained in the accepted answer of the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526528/1331040

Comment: Ya, I've gone through it. Is he telling that the global angular cli is current angular cli version?

Comment: You have system modules and project modules. These differ.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I've not found my answer there. He answered for the question if both version are required or not and if two versions should by in sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your global angular version is that of the version you've installed systemwide with the `-g` flag. Your local angular version is the one you've installed inside your project folder.