# Why i get warning that my global version is bigger then my local. Where the local is coming from?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I wanted to use angular version 10 so i installed it

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@10
```

when i check

```
ng --version
```

i get

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 10.23.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
```

if i try to run in my folder

```
ng new my-app
```

i get warning

```
Your global Angular CLI version (10.2.1) is greater than your local
version (7.0.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
```

i don't understand - when i installed only the angular version 10, i get even warning for angular 7 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)

Answer (score 0):

When it refers to local version it is application dependency so,
check version of @angular/cli in devDependencies block in package.json file.