# Run typescript on project version of Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I need to be able to run projects with different versions of Angular on the same computer.

Is there a way to use the version of angular only in the package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a project with ng serve, Angular uses the local version by default.
So it will use the @angular/cli version you have in your project.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526528/15036361) explains it well.