# install specific angular version not work

Tags: angular, version

I currently have version 9 of angular, now i am trying to update my version of angular, for which I have followed tutorials but none of them work for me.

The steps I am doing is the following.

First I uninstall my current version of angular

[image]

Then, i clear cache:

[image]

Then i install specific angular CLI:

[image]

but when i run ng version it shows me this:

[image]

Is the version installed correctly? What does "local version" mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)

Answer (score 1):

The local version is the one defined in the `package.json` file of the project you're working on. If you want to use Angular 13 in your project, you need to update `package.json`. Be warned, however, that you'll also need to update all dependencies, and that can be thorny. Sometimes it's easier to create a brand new project and copy/pasta everything across…

P.S. More recent versions of Angular CLI expose the `ng update` command which help you update a project running a previous version. I don't think V9 had it though…

Answer (score 0):

The Angular have it's own documentation for updating angular cli, put your info into the form and follow that he told you to do.
The recommendation is to update version to version;

https://update.angular.io/