# Your global Angular CLI version (14.2.3) is greater than your local version (11.2.10). The local Angular CLI version is used

Tags: angular-cli, config

*Your global Angular CLI version (14.2.3) is greater than your local version (11.2.10). The local Angular CLI version is used.*

*To disable this warning use "`ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false`".*

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily an issue, just Angular indicating that the project's Angular version is `11.2.10` and your global Angular version is `14.2.3`.

This may be desirable, for example if a work project needs to remain on Angular `11.2.10`. It would be annoying for you to have to reinstall Angular globally every time you wanted to use the project. Angular CLI takes this pain away by using a lower version of Angular on your behalf.

However if you have control over which version of Angular the project can be set to and want the error to go away, you will have to bring your project's Angular version in line with your global version (in other words, upgrade the project from Angular `11.2.10` to Angular `14.2.3`). Typically via command:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@14.2.3
```

See this question for more guidance/answers:
[Global Angular CLI version greater than local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version)