# basic "hello world" react app is throwing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using ReactJS framework/library, I have created a basic "Hello World" react app on windows platform after following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm) tutorial, but it throws errors when I run it using `C:\Users\username\Desktop\reactApp>npm start` command on cmd. Please tell what is the problem?

**Error:**

```
> reactApp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\username\Desktop\reactApp
> webpack-dev-server --hot

'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactApp@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactApp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactApp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactApp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\Desktop\reactApp\npm-debug.log
```

**index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "index.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

**main.js** file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**App.jsx** file

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

**package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "reactApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js** file

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install webpack --save` and `npm install webpack-dev-server --save` ?

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35810172/3551786)

Comment: yes! @FiriceNguyen

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it should have installed this module `webpack-dev-server` by itself since it is mentioned as a production dependency in `package.json` by default. However may be your `npm` module skipped it somehow or did not install properly. You can delete the `node_modules` folder manually and do `npm install` again and it should work fine.