# 'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: npm, webpack, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server

I cloned this Webpack Starter package through github using gitbash following a tutorial on pluralsight. I am trying to access webpack through Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal but i get the following error. I am new to this so kindly help me on this.

I am running a command

```
 Raza Zaidi@RazaZaidi-PC MINGW64 ~/webpack-starter (master)
$ npm run dev
```

and then following error occurs

```
> yet-another-webpack-es6-starterkit@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Raza Zaidi\webpack-starter
> webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js

'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! yet-another-webpack-es6-starterkit@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yet-another-webpack-es6-starterkit@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Raza Zaidi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-14T20_16_29_017Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

running

> npm install -g webpack-dev-server

in cmd as an administrator solved my problem. I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 31):

Webpack command should be present in location: `node_modules\.bin\`

In this case in package.json file we are referring to webpack-dev-server, but locally webpack-dev-server doesn't exist.

First run following command for global installation:

```sh
npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```

Second execute local installation command, which will create `node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server`:

```sh
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

Comment: Even though webpack-dev-server was in my package.json, I had to re-run `npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev` to resolve my issue, didn't need to execute the first command

Comment: Above solved my problem as well. Why do we manually have to install dependencies specified in package.json? Why are they not installed on npm install?

Answer (score 5):

For me, instead of installing webpack-dev-server globally, I simply uninstalled and reinstalled the local package:

```
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

Comment: In my case, I had already installed locally, but a re-install fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Webpack & WDS need **webpack-cli** package, I recommend you to downloaded if your Webpack version is 4 or higher

Comment: i ran "npm install -g webpack-dev-server" in cmd and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

first I've install webpack-dev-server in global

```
npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```

after installation I got this error..
***Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'***

this is version not matching problem, in my code I used these dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-validator": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

so change webpack-dev-server version in global

```
npm install -g webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.0
```

in my case this was worked

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version, in my case switching to last node version helped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by typing command: npm update

Comment: This is the solution if you've forked a repository, and try to run in without installing its packages. I got this using yarn rather than npm, so the solution for me was just to type "yarn"

Answer (score 0):

if package.json file already exist with webpack, webpack-cli and dev server then simple use command npm install. Otherwise
use commond npm install webpack@4.30.0 or
npm install --save-dev webpack@latest
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli@latest
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server@latest
"webpack": "^4.30.0",
"webpack-bundle-size-analyzer": "^3.0.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).