# webpack-dev-server is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, makehuman

**Dear Guys**

I'm running **makehuman-js** project from [Github](https://github.com/makehuman-js/makehuman-js-example)

I followed the steps:

```
1- extract the project in AT folder

2- npm install

3- npm test
```

but there is a problem here:

**webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

I attached my error in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LQEY.png)

also here is my project folder:
[root project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUwNc.png)

After updating my npm and node js. I finally could load the project on web browser, but still have this "Error3" [image: Error3]

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem, I spent a lot of time, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849282/webpack-dev-server-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 3):

author of the package here.

What's happening is that `npm test` is running this line '"test": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.test.config.js --open"' from the projects package.json file. The problem occurs when it can't find the terminal command webpack-dev-server in the system PATH.

You can fix this by installing webpack 2 globally with `npm install -g webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.10` (thats the version from package.json). If it still isn't found you may need to add your global node_modules folder to your PATH environmental variable.

Another approach is going to the package.json replacing "webpack-dev-server" with ".\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server" which is the relative local path for windows. Make sure you also run `npm install --dev` to install development dependancies (I've added this to the readme now).

The project hasn't been used by many people yet so there are probably a few rough spots where it's confusing. It's great your interested though, so if you have other problems you can open an issue on the github repository and I'll try to help/fix it when I have time.

Comment: Thank you , @wassname but I face another problem too, the first one is that in mocha folder which is in test folder, there isn't pose_spec.js and when I commented this line from index.js my program could compile it successfully but some errors spears again. I will upload the image of error to my question, with the name of "error3" could you help me in continuous? thanks alott