# Webpack error after updated some dependencies

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, autoprefixer

I am updating the packages of my app, but I am getting some errors when I trying to update to the latest ones.

**My Project is running at http://localhost:8080/**

these are the packs from the old project which if I use runs perfectly

```
   "autoprefixer": "^9.6.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

I am trying update to these ones to be fair to the latest versions:

```
"autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
"postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
"webpack": "^5.9.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

**my GitHub code: https://github.com/openbooknoobdeveloper/pizzareact**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ]
};
```

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  devtool: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ]
};
```

**if I update the packages I get this error when I run** `npm start` :

```
$ npm start

> react-complete-guide@1.0.0 start A:\github\LAB\test-webpack-version-pizza
> webpack-dev-server

'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-complete-guide@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-complete-guide@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-17T15_41_12_536Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849282/webpack-dev-server-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) help you?

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is caused by migration webpack 4.x to 5.x. You have to change the start script to start the webpack dev-server: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/

```
"start": "webpack serve"
```

Mind your further npm args.