# 'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: npm, webpack

I have the same problem with npm run dev after install webpack. I tried to look for the solution in here, and the closest answer I found is this: [webpack is not recognized as a internal or external command,operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810172/webpack-is-not-recognized-as-a-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or/35817969#35817969), but unsuccessful to resolve the issue after set up the path.

Comment: I set the path that also showing npm in the Roaming directory, but still cannot compile with the npm run dev process.