# Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'Store<ApplicationState>' but required in type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'. TS2741

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I've got this error after update @react-material/core, and I don't know how to resolve this.

I tried to update react-redux and redux-thunk libraries with no success.

This is part of my store file:

```
const store = isDevMode
  ? createStore<ApplicationState>(
      rootReducer,
      initialState,
      composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
    )
  : createStore<ApplicationState>(
      rootReducer,
      initialState,
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    );
```

This is the error:

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO6SO.png)

I'm just trying to resolve this to generate a new version.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into this issue this morning. I tried updating my @types/react-redux, but wasn't having any luck. Eventually I just added this as a workaround to the type error:

```
  <Provider store={store as any}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
```

Comment: answer from Olvis seems a better way to solve the issue

Answer (score 25):

You should update redux to 4.0.3 (see: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3466)